# What is meant by "strongest inequality here" in this proof of generalized uncertainty principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In proving a generalized uncertainty principle, Ballentine (page 223 of the first edition) arrives at any expression
$$Tr(\rho A_0^2) +\omega Tr(\rho C)+\omega^2Tr(\rho B_0^2) \geq 0$$
where $A_0 \equiv A - \langle A \rangle$ and similarly for $B$, and where $[A,B] = iC$ for context.

At any rate, his next step is to say that "The strongest inequality will be obtained if we choose $\omega$ so as to minimize the quadratic form." I am taking that to mean "any inequality obtained when we choose $\omega$ so as to minimize the quadratic form will imply (as a necessary consequence) any other inequality we might have obtained for any other choice of $\omega$".

That is, at the minimum value $\omega_0$ of the quadratic form this inequality reads
$$Tr(\rho A_0^2)Tr(\rho B_0^2) \geq (Tr(\rho C))^2/4,$$
which is of course the generalized uncertainty principle. This is an inequality between the coefficients of the quadratic form. What I think Ballentine is saying is that any other such inequality (obtained at some other fixed $\omega$) is implied by this one (and is hence "less strong").

How can I see this is true though?

Comment: Calling the quadratic form $f(\omega)$, you define the minimizing $\omega_0$ by $f(\omega)\geq f(\omega_0)$,and $f(\omega_0)\geq 0$. So, $\forall \omega,~~f(\omega)\geq f(\omega_0)\geq 0$. You expect something else?

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. Let me do that right now @CosmasZachos

Comment: Edited just now. @CosmasZachos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the positive-semidefinite quadratic form
$$
f(\omega)= a+\omega b +\omega^2 c= (1,\omega) \begin{pmatrix} a&b/2\\b/2& c\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ \omega\end{pmatrix}.
$$
So its eigenvalues must be positive semidefinite, and hence its determinant, $ac-b^2/4\geq 0$. Note *c* cannot vanish, unless *b* vanishes as well.

The form is minimized for
$$
b+2c \omega_0 =0 ~~~\leadsto ~~~
 \omega_0 =  -b/2c \implies \\
f(\omega_0)= (ac-b^2/4)/c \geq 0.
$$

Comment: I see, thank you! I've gone ahead and accepted, but I'm wondering what information the minimum even gives us given your analysis above?

Comment: I'm not sure, beyond the zero, the ready saturation condition for the UP...

Comment: Ah I see. You are saying that via the first method you simply establish the UP, but via the second method you establish something extra about the saturating case?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm splitting methods.... Whatever works for you...

Comment: Touche. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
I(\omega) \equiv {\rm Tr}(\rho A_0^2) + \omega {\rm Tr}(\rho C) + \omega^2{\rm Tr}(\rho B_0^2)
$$
Based on the premise of your question, I take it that Ballentine has proven $I(\omega) \geq 0$ for any value of $\omega$.

Now let $\omega_{\rm min}$ be the value of $\omega$ that minimizes $I(\omega)$. Then we have trivially that $I(\omega) \geq I(\omega_{\rm min})$ for all $\omega$.

Chaining these inequalities together,
$$
I(\omega) \geq I(\omega_{\rm min}) \geq 0
$$
so therefore $I(\omega_{\rm min})\geq 0$ is the strongest inequality in the family of inequalities $I(\omega) \geq 0$.

Comment: I am editing right now but I don't think that's what I'm getting at, seeing as the "strong inequality" being referred to by Ballentine is with respect to the coefficients, not the values of the quadratic form at different $\omega$. It is my fault for being unclear.

Comment: Edited just now.

Comment: @EE18 Even with your edit I'd still give the same answer. $\omega_{\rm min}$ will be a function of the coefficients of the quadratic form, so $I(\omega_{\rm min})\geq 0$ will be an inequality relating coefficients of the quadratic form.

Comment: But I'm not sure how that tells us that no extra information relating the coefficients is gained from observing $I(\omega) \geq 0$ for some other $\omega$?

Comment: @EE18 Pick a specific value of $\omega$. Let's say that numerically $\omega_{\rm min}=10$, so pick $\omega=11$. Then $I(11) \geq 0$ is still a relationship among the "coefficients". However, the bound is weaker than $I(\omega_{\rm min})$, and therefore is implied by the $I(\omega_{\rm min})$ bound. The same will be true for any value of $\omega$ you choose.

Comment: I *think* I see -- thank you!